# Subsequent gradle tasks should be executed though first task failed it should continue execution of next tasks

Tags: gradle

In the build file there are multiple tasks present. Taks A, Task B, Task C. When its configured with Jenkins as gradle TaskA taskB TaskC and job is started if task A is failed then subsequent tasks failed. But we want to ensure that though taskA failed next task taskB and taskC should be executed irrespective of taskA.

1. Can we set the executing sequence for Gradle tasks
2. Dont want to use mustRunAfter. Tried that but its not useful for us we have another task which needs to have manage same dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue execution after some task's failure, you can set this task `ignoreFailures` property to true (it's false by default).

```
taskA.ignoreFailures = true
```

In that case, even if `taskA` fails, execution continues.

Answer (score 0):

We are using --continue where if task A failed still it execute next subsequent tasks without failures. I found this options as most easy one instead of using the ignoreFailures.